# Update to Drools Excel Decision Table Breaks Rules

Tags: excel, drools

I have an Excel decision table in Drools that works just fine. I need to make an update to the final column (in this case, the results) with new values. When I update the fields, the rules engine no longer returns any matches. I am not updating the conditions at all, just the cell values. If I revert to the previous version of the Excel file, everything is fine. Is there some gotcha with updating a decision table that I need to be aware of?

EDIT: Per request, here's bit more specificity. I have an xls decision table with conditions and rules. The last column is the Action and outputs a percentage value based on the rule criteria. Here's an sample from the DRL:

```
#From row number: 12
rule "BaseTableRatingFactorRule_12"

    when
        factor:BaseTableRatingFactorsDTO(tableRatingPercentage >= 101, tableRatingPercentage <= 125, ageOfInsured == 1, contractSeriesCode not in("THRIVENT UL 04", "VUL 04"), insuredSexCode == "M", tobacco == "0", ruleEffectiveDate >= "01/01/2001", ruleEffectiveDate <= "31/12/9999")
    then
        factor.getRResult().setTableRatingCommissionablePremiumFactor(0.07);
end
```

I need to update the percentages returned, i.e in the above example change .07 to .18, however when I update just that one column with the new percentages the rules no longer match. I have matched the formatting the of the original document, etc. If I revert back to the previous version of the .xls before any changes everything works fine.

Comment: Can you be anymore specific on what your change is? Does the decision table compile properly after the edit?

Comment: Whatever it is: it isn't due to changing `07` to `18` or similar changes. - How is the knowledge base built from the XLS, and is there a check for errors? It's possible that no rules are built due to some error.

Comment: Is that what the rule looks like before or after you have made your update?

Comment: Before and after the rules look the same, as far as I can tell. The only difference is the value.

Comment: Okay, so I'm not sure why this is, but generating the DRL file and referencing that in the application instead of the .xls works fine. I'm not going to question it.